# Why is pressure in a fluid lower where velocity is higher? (Without using Bernoulli's equation)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, kinematics, fluid-statics

So, it is said that wherever the velocity of the fluid is lower, the pressure is higher. I don't know see how this is reasonable. Can someone please explain this to me without using Bernoulli's equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a streamline along which the fluid velocity is increasing. This means that the fluid is accelerating, so there must be a force. Forces in an ideal fluid are related to differences in pressure, so the pressure must be decreasing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'the pressure must be *decreasing*', at the end? I.e. if the fluid is accelerating along the streamline.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

You always hear that an increase in fluid velocity causes a decrease in pressure, but actually it is the other way around: the lower pressure causes the fluid to accelerate into the lower pressure zone. (This applies to steady state flow at subsonic speeds.) In common physics problems, where a fluid speeds up and then slows down again back to its original speed, e.g. flowing through a narrow section of pipe or air over an aircraft wing, the slowing down must happen because the air is moving into a higher pressure area and so experiences a decelerating force. In a steady state the force resulting from the pressure difference is always exactly enough to slow the fluid down back to the ambient speed, because if not there would not be a steady state.